# Focusing a ReportViewer control

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set a focus on my ReportViewer control. There are no reports binded to it or whatsoever. I have this code on my `Form1_Load` event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    this.reportViewer1.Select();
    this.reportViewer1.Focus();
    if(this.reportViewer1.Focused)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(false);
    }
}
```

After the form loads, the else block is being executed. Why does that keep happening even though I already made a call to the `.Focus()` and `.Select()` functions?